# How to change the Background of Layout dynamically while dragging layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to change the background of layout dynamically while dragging the layout.

I used the following code for touch listener.

```
RelativeLayout   rlImages.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    RelativeLayout   half_left.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());


private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinkcircle);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pinkcircle);

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My dragListener class :

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.halfcircle_left);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinkcircle);

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int dragAction = event.getAction();
        final View dragView = (View) event.getLocalState();

        dragView.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // dragView.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                dragView.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                // Do nothing
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                dragView.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                // v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                // v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
                dragView.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change the background of layout while dragging it,but couldnt able to do that in any of DragEvents

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `MyTouchListener` and `MyDragListener` to a View?

Comment: rlImages.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
   half_left.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

Comment: I have edited please check

Comment: As soon as you get the `onTouch()` callback, you change the Views visibility: `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`. Why?

Comment: It should look like it is dragging with my finger movement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40171/discussion-between-jeffrey-klardie-and-user1891910)

Answer (score 0):

In the onTouchListener you need to change the background before you start the drag, because once you call `view.startDrag()`, the view gets duplicated. Then, when the drag ends and before it becomes visible again, you need to reset the background to what it was in the beginning (or whatever other background you want).

The following shows how that works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // doing view stuff...
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            // set background of dragged view to red
            view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);  
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        View dragView = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from " + layoutview.toString());
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
                // reset background of dragged view
                dragView.setBackground(null); 
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) dragView.getParent();
                owner.removeView(dragView);
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
                container.addView(dragView);
                dragView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```